# TextInputLayout showing Floating Drawable with cursor

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

When I use textinputlayout with two floating actions shows up don't know where it's causing check out this image for the floating just below the cursor [image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgColor"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:boxBackgroundMode="none"
        app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:padding="0dp"


        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:hint="@string/addtitlehint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_20sp"

            android:textColorHighlight="@color/highLightColor"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            >
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This image shows that if I select any text can't figure out where this happening..

Also if I select a particular text it shows like this.
check the issue image for two floating drawables [image]

Comment: Post your activity/fragment code